# Can I define a "factor" data type for a field?

Tags: ms-access-2013, fieldtype

Let's say I want my table to have a column `Color`. The data type is `Short Text`. I intend this to have values like `Red`, `Blue`, and `Green`. However, I don't want values like `Sugarplum`.

In fact, I *know* that in this particular able, the values can only be `Red`, `Blue`, or `Green` - not even `Yellow`. So I would like the user to see an error when he tries to type in `Yellow`. In fact, I would like there to be drop down in each cell from which the user can select `Red`, `Blue`, or `Green`.

What is the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict the values of your column, you might want to add them in a Validation Rule in the table design > propereties for that field.

You can simply use a rule like

```
"red" Or "green" Or "blue"
```

(this does allow all upper and lower case compositions of the same word, like RED, as well).

To show the possibilities in a  drop down list, again go into the properties in the design view and in the lookup-tab, you can choose for 'list box' and in the Row Source Type property select 'value list'. In the Row Source property, add the colors you want.

Comment: I have found that I can create a new table, like `List of colors`, or a query, and then set the `Row Source Type` to `Table/Query` for an even nicer system.

Comment: You are completely right, using a table would be an even better solution (I only responded to the question at hand but could have offered that advise indeed).